# How can i use multiple pagedown in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagedown

I tried the below code for that, but it adds pagedown buttons to only the first `.wmd-input`.

[image]

```
if ($(".wmd-input").length > 0) {
    var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
    var help = function () { alert("Do you need help?"); }
    var options = {
        helpButton: { handler: help },
        strings: {quoteexample: "whatever you're quoting, put it right here"}
    };
    var editors = [];
    var i = 0;

    $(".wmd-input").each(function() {
        editors[i] = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "", options);
        editors[i].run();
        i = i + 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: You should put the solution as an Answer yourself, and then accept it (instead of editing the question). See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like i have to add unique ID for each element of wmd. I mean `wmd-input`, `wmd-preview` and `wmd-button-bar`. I modified this id attributes programmatically. This can be done with modifying manually but my length of inputs are dynamic.

```
  // make wmd's id's unique
  var pBox = $(this).parents(".box");
  $(pBox).find("textarea").attr('id', "wmd-input" + i);
  $(pBox).children("#wmd-preview").attr('id', "wmd-preview" + i);
  $(pBox).find("#wmd-button-bar").attr('id', "wmd-button-bar" + i);
```

So when this ID attributes is set, i called the editor with postfix variable and problem  solved.

```
editors[i] = new Markdown.Editor(converters[i], i, options);
```

[image]

```
 if ($(".wmd-input").length > 0) {
    var converters = [];
    var editors = [];
    var i = 1;
    $(".wmd-input").each(function() {
      converters[i] = new Markdown.Converter();
      var help = function () { alert("Do you need help?"); }
      var options = {
         helpButton: { handler: help },
         strings: {quoteexample: "whatever you're quoting, put it right here"}
      };

      // make wmd's id's unique
      var pBox = $(this).parents(".box");
      $(pBox).find("textarea").attr('id', "wmd-input" + i);
      $(pBox).children("#wmd-preview").attr('id', "wmd-preview" + i);
      $(pBox).find("#wmd-button-bar").attr('id', "wmd-button-bar" + i);

      editors[i] = new Markdown.Editor(converters[i], i, options);
      editors[i].run();
      i = i + 1;
    });
 }
```